# What does "implicit anonymous class parameter" mean in this context?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, the following code has the variable `commandBytes` colored to indicate an "implicit anonymous class parameter":

```
public boolean writeCommand( byte[] commandBytes ) {
if( writeCommandInProgress.compareAndSet( false, true ) ) { 
    writeSubscription = bleDevice
            .establishConnection( asBleServiceRef, false )
            .flatMap( rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic( asInputCharId, commandBytes) )
            .subscribe( 
                    characteristicValue -> { 
                        writeCommandInProgress.set( false ); 
                        if( !Arrays.equals( characteristicValue, commandBytes ) )
                            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Data read back from writeCommand() doesn't match input");
                    },
                    throwable -> Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Error in writeCommand: " + commandBytes.toString() + "; " + throwable.getMessage() )
            );
    return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

I can't figure out what this means. The description on JetBrains' help site isn't really  helping: "That's a local variable which is used by an anonymous or local class inside the method and thus becomes a field of the anonymous class." How does this apply? Is it something I need to worry about?

Comment: I was curious and Google'd and I see you are the only person on the internet asking this question :-) The explanation of what it means seems pretty obvious, but it's not exactly clear what the implications of that might be. A couple guesses: Perhaps it's just to let you know that it will hold a reference so may not be GC'd? To warn of potential multi-threading issues?

Comment: On a different note, if this is production code, whoever has to maintain it is going to hate you. Nobody is going to be able to look at this and determine what it does without spending a lot of time.

Comment: Actually not production code, but a slightly-adapted snippet from the authors of the RxAndroidBle library, for testing purposes. As for the explanation being obvious, help me by pointing out the anonymous class that the variable is an implicit parameter of?

Comment: @RobertLewis can u plz respond..! to my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colouring indicates the parameter or local variable is declared outside and used inside an anonymous class (or lambda in this case). To make this possible the javac compiler will create a synthetic field in the anonymous class to store the variable in. You can see this by inspecting the bytecode (`View > Show Bytecode`).

This is not something to worry about, it is not a warning, it's just a colouring of the syntax to provide information. It does mean the variable is implicitly or explicitly final, so it's not possible to reassign it without breaking compilation.

Comment: Ah, I failed to make the connection between "anonymous class" and "lambda". Perhaps JetBrains should consider updating this message for Java 8.